# Error starting Cassandra 3.4

Tags: java, linux, memory, memory-management, cassandra

I have installed the Cassandra from the main website. I keep on getting an error each time I try to start it

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f85b2000000, 33554432, 0) failed;
>   error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
>
> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>   Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 33554432 bytes for committing reserved memory.
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   /root/hs_err_pid6951.log

The error in the log says

> OS:DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04 DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
>   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
>
> uname:Linux 3.13.0-79-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 14:27:58 UTC
>   2016 x86_64 libc:glibc 2.19 NPTL 2.19  rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k,
>   NPROC 3750, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity load average:0.30 0.12 0.07
>
> /proc/meminfo: MemTotal:         501776 kB MemFree:            6796 kB
>   Buffers:             788 kB Cached:            26948 kB SwapCached:
>   0 kB Active:           439400 kB Inactive:          17168 kB
>   Active(anon):     429012 kB Inactive(anon):     9448 kB Active(file): 
>   10388 kB Inactive(file):     7720 kB Unevictable:           0 kB
>   Mlocked:               0 kB SwapTotal:             0 kB SwapFree:
>   0 kB Dirty:                20 kB Writeback:             0 kB
>   AnonPages:        428864 kB Mapped:            20972 kB Shmem:
>   9580 kB Slab:              20252 kB SReclaimable:      10616 kB
>   SUnreclaim:         9636 kB KernelStack:        1432 kB PageTables:
>   5860 kB NFS_Unstable:          0 kB Bounce:                0 kB
>   WritebackTmp:          0 kB CommitLimit:      250888 kB Committed_AS: 
>   1402952 kB VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB VmallocUsed:        7964 kB
>   VmallocChunk:   34359722876 kB HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
>   AnonHugePages:         0 kB HugePages_Total:       0 HugePages_Free:
>   0 HugePages_Rsvd:        0 HugePages_Surp:        0 Hugepagesize:
>   2048 kB DirectMap4k:       40952 kB DirectMap2M:      483328 kB
>   DirectMap1G:           0 kB
>
> CPU:total 1 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 45
>   stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1,
>   sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, tsc
>
> /proc/cpuinfo: processor  : 0 vendor_id   : GenuineIntel cpu family   : 6
>   model     : 45 model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630L 0 @ 2.00GHz
>   stepping  : 7 microcode   : 0x1 cpu MHz       : 1999.999 cache size   : 15360 KB
>   physical id   : 0 siblings    : 1 core id     : 0 cpu cores   : 1 apicid      : 0
>   initial apicid    : 0 fpu     : yes fpu_exception : yes cpuid level   : 13
>   wp        : yes flags     : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr
>   pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb
>   rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon rep_good nopl eagerfpu pni
>   pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt
>   tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat xsaveopt vnmi
>   ept tsc_adjust bogomips   : 3999.99 clflush size  : 64 cache_alignment    :
>   64 address sizes  : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual power management:
>
> Memory: 4k page, physical 501776k(6796k free), swap 0k(0k free)
>
> vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.77-b03) for linux-amd64
>   JRE (1.8.0_77-b03), built on Mar 20 2016 22:00:46 by "java_re" with
>   gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

Comment: Your machine is out of memory. C* tries to allocate 32MB of native (off-heap) memory, but your machine only has 6.8MB to offer.

Answer (score 0):

Due to insufficient memory, Cassandra is not starting.Your system is not having the sufficient memory to fulfill the requirements of the Cassandra.

Comment: I googled the problem but most articles claim it's not the memory. I am running it as the root user so it should not be a process limit issue. Here is one of the [articles I read](http://serverfault.com/questions/662992/java-on-linux-insufficient-memory-even-though-there-is-plenty-of-available-memor)

Comment: I don't think that the "user" is limiting factor here. Can you try running  Cassandra and "free -m" command at the same time and share the stats?